# で or に: how does the meaning of a sentence change?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-に, particle-で, sentence

Supposing I wanted to say "I see the fireworks at the summer festival". Would this be:

> 夏{なつ}祭{まつ}り**で**花{はな}火{び}を見{み}ます。

or

> 夏祭り**に**花火を見ます。

If both are correct, how does the meaning differ between each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both are correct.

The differences are:

1. 夏祭りに花火を見ます This is a regular phrase for "I'll watch the fireworks at
   the summer festival."
2. 夏祭りで花火を見ます This would stress **at**. It has a nuance that "I have
   many chances to watch the fireworks but I will watch them at the
   summer festival."

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct, but my reasoning will differ from @S.Wakisaka's.

「夏祭り**で**花火を見る」 treats the summer festival as a **spatial point (location)** for watching fireworks.

「夏祭り**に**花火を見る」 treats the summer festival as a **temporal point (timing)**  for watching fireworks.

Starting around 0:25 in the video below, hear this singer say 「秋祭{あきまつ}り**に**買{か}った指輪{ゆびわ}、小指{こゆび}にしています」.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jdlj7fXtFyg

Comment: This explanation is very interesting and very true, although 祭り is a word that specifies time and place, but 休み only does time. It's worth to know. 〜に & 〜で these postpositional particles have many variations of usages.  I guess, the question implies the difference of ベッドで寝る and ベッドに寝る, this example is clear to lead my answer.

Comment: ^ The 休み was clearly just a typo, you know... It's been corrected. And, the difference of に and で in ベッドに寝る/ベッドで寝る is quite different from that of に and で in 秋祭りに見る/秋祭りで見る. You'd say 秋祭り**に**見た as a response to "_When_ did you see~~?" and 秋祭り**で**見た to "_Where_ did you see ~~?", no?